# Reference currently stored value during type conversion of custom NDB property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I've created a custom NDB property, and I'm looking for a way to reference the currently stored property value (the value already saved to the datastore) from the `_to_base_type` method:

```
class CustomProperty(StructuredProperty):
  def __init__(self, **kwds):
    super(CustomProperty, self).__init__(CustomModel, **kwds)

  def _validate(self, value):
    assert isinstance(value, CustomObject)

  def _to_base_type(self, value):
    # reference currently stored value here <--
    return CustomModel()

  def _from_base_type(self, value):
    return CustomObject()
```

Is this possible?